# How to identify which model object has been chosen?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

How to identify certain object which has been chosen using `ModelChoiceField`?

In my case, I have model `Language`:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price_per_sign = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shortcut+': '+self.name
```

And form:

```
class FreelancerRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    language = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all().order_by('shortcut'))
```

In my **views.py**, I don't know how to identify which model has been chosen.

```
print freelancer_registration_form.cleaned_data['language']
```

returns method str of the object which is sometimes not enough to identify the language. Is it possible to get an `id` instead of this `str` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `print` over an object, python will call `__str__` method on the object (hear is the instance of Language Model which is selected in form)

If you want to get the `id` of chosen instance you should do something like:

```
chosen_language = freelancer_registration_form.cleaned_data['language']
chosen_language_id = chosen_language.id
```

or change the definition of `__str__` method, like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'id: {self.id}, shortcut: {self.shortcut}, name: {self.name}'.format(
self=self)
```

`DjangoForm` will map `request.POST` or `request.GET` or any dictionary as a data to each filed's type. In this case it will map them to Language Model instances for `ModelChoiceField`.

Answer (score 1):

You *have* the Language object. Obviously, if you print it, you'll get the Unicode representation. But the element is the full object, with all its attributes including id.